# how to show icon with title in dialog

Tags: android

I'm using a dialog in my code with a custom layout;
the problem is that I'm confused on how to show an icon with a title.

I'm not using alert dialog: I'm using a dialog.
Below is my code.
When I'm using this line:

```
// dialog2.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

the app crashes

```
  dialog2 = new Dialog(context);
    View vLoad = LayoutInflater.from(ActivityHome.this).inflate(
            R.layout.timer, null);

    dialog2.setContentView(vLoad);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.text2);

    Button closedailog = (Button) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.dailogexit);


    String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>red</font>";

   String[]     documentlisencearray = documentlisence.split(",");

    if(documentlisencearray[1]!=null)
    {String newString1 = new String(documentlisencearray[1].toString());
    String[]        documentobject = newString1.split("=");

     text1.setText(documentobject[0]);
     text2.setText(documentobject[1]);
    }

    dialog2.setTitle("Documents Due Alert");

    dialog2.setTitle( Html.fromHtml("<font color='#ff0000'>Documents Due Alert</font>"));
//  dialog2.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    dialog2.setCancelable(false);
    dialog2.show();

        closedailog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //
                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });

}


        this is my xml///timer.xml///


                   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"

  android:id="@+id/layouttimer">

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>


   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" ></TextView>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/dailogexit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="OK " >

</Button>


      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: But if you are using `custom xml` file then set icon in that file for `ImageView`.

Comment: but im using dialog2.setTitle("Documents Due Alert");iwant to show icon lwft of this text

Comment: So you can call `dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`

Comment: i update my xml   ur code dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher); show error

Comment: what error did you get at that line?

Comment: The method setIcon(int) is undefined for the type Dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this for your Dialog

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutfile);
dialog2.setTitle("Documents Due Alert");

dialog.show();
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.your_icon)
```

Comment: thnx this line work  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);

Comment: what does mean b this line Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON

Comment: It is indicate that the flag for having an icon on the left side of the title bar

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
**dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);**
dialog.setTitle(R.string.my_dialog_title);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog_layout);
dialog.setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.some_icon);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: ur code dialog.setFeature cause errror crash app
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDrawableState(PhoneWindow.java:3023)